# PHP CURL timing out , no matter what timeout is

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am writing a little program in php utilizing curl to login and download some reports from a service. The program works fine up until this one point where it is supposed to get the report, then the program keeps timing out with the below message. Any ideas or suggestions? The server I connect to originally is a MS IIS Server, then it jumps to this AkamaiGHost server for reports.

Below are the curl setopts I am using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CERTINFO,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,'cacert.pem');


Report Response:
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 250
Expires: Fri, 05 Jul 2013 19:14:43 GMT
Date: Fri, 05 Jul 2013 19:14:43 GMT
Connection: close

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Gateway Timeout - In read </TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Gateway Timeout</H1>
The proxy server did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;1&#46;ed690317&#46;1373051683&#46;bb2c2f0
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Post your CURL request maybe.. are you storing the cookies/auth appropriately for the next request?

Comment: you need to figure out why akamai's proxy can't reach whatever server you're trying to get to.

Comment: inside the browser the call is done almost instantly...inside of curl it timeouts.. The cookies and auth are not a problem, I am logging in, grabbing another page, and then grabbing another page..

Comment: Your browser on your local machine that directly connects to the target, instead of Akamai works?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your IIS server (or the server you're running the script on) has no route to the AkamaiGHost server - this could be a firewall issue, DNS issue, or some other connectivity problem (perhaps the AkamaiGHost is not setup to listen to requests from your server?).

You should check that you can make outgoing requests on the server.

Try logging onto the server that the script is being run on, and ping the AkamaiGHost server -if that works try a command line curl (not SSL) - if that works then your problem could well be due to something interfering with outgoing connections on the SSL port (443) - such as your firewall.